# Read particular Excel calendar in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have an Excel calendar (with days off information), structured in way i can't parse it directly.
Attached is an example of the calendar I have.
I want to transform it into a DataFrame with all days in column, and all person in rows.

I can't make it, I am not good enough in Python. Can someone help me?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should to use MultiIndex, and use 2 primary columns to index and 2 primary rows as a columns names. To do that, you need use headers and index_col when you read the file:

```
pd.read_excel(file_name, header=[0,1,2],index_col=[0,1])
```

and it should to see like that:
[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quinm.png)